# How to enable raw output on Chromium's console?

Tags: javascript, chromium

I'm trying to inspect some elements I'm querying from Chromium's console. However, instead of plain text, Chromium renders a little UI (see images below). How can I get raw text, as in NodeJS' console?

[image]

I looked into Chromium's settings, but I found nothing (at least not obvious if it exists) to change that behavio

Comment: What do you expect that the plain text would look like?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier, just plain text, like in NodeJS.

Comment: I guess you could `JSON.stringify` it before calling `console.log`, but I have trouble understanding what you mean by "plain text" for a DOM node.

Comment: Or you can use `.innerHTML` for DOM nodes.

Comment: @GuillaumeBrunerie, I'd like to see something similar as if I executed `console.log(global)` in NodeJs: Just object properties, no HTML text.

Comment: Sounds like trade of a Swiss watch for an hourglass. Why not just make your own handler for such kind of output and name it `console.raw`?